# External command fails with return code 0xC0000005 when called from Python but works in console

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, external

I have a python 3.5 script running under Windows that is calling an external problem (tblastn from the BLAST+ suite to be precise) on a number of files. With most of these files it runs fine but on some it fails with return code 0xC0000005. If I take the exact same command line call and run it from the console in the same current working directory it executes fine.

I am currently running the command with `subprocess.Popen`, like this:

```
childProcess = subprocess.Popen(blast_cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     universal_newlines=True,shell=True)
```

and then calling `subprocess.poll()` until it completes. I am multi-threading this by running four processes simultaneously but it still happens if I force it to run one at a time. The same thing happens with `os.system`, `subprocess.run()`, `subprocess.call()` and `subprocess.check_call()` and it happens whether I set `shell` to `True` or `False`.

Which file(s) it fails on is/are the same each time I run the code but the same file will work if put into a different list of files to process. Changing the calling method sometimes changes which files fail so using `os.system` can cause different files to fail compared to `subprocess.Popen`. Thus it doesn't appear to be down to which file I am invoking tblastn on.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this behaviour?

Or if anyone knows what could be different between running in created process (the documentation says it uses `CreateProcess()`) as compared to running from the command line then at least I'd have somewhere to start?

Comment: I have an idea about how to debug it, but I'm not familiar with tblastn; do you compile it from source or have the ability to?

Comment: I got it as an .exe; I could get hold of the source and re-compile it but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Okay - I take it you're on windows then? Don't know about windows but on linux you could prepend "valgrind" to the "blast_cmd" list and provide it a log file to output to (its a valgrind arg). That would record the stacktrace of where things failed (though it would help if compiled in debugmode if it's a segfault). This wouldn't be so you can debug the program but to help see if there's a particular argument it fails on or can't load. Maybe some resource isn't being passed the same way as it is on the shell (one auto-completes the full path name, e.g.)

Comment: Yeah, under Windows. I'm pretty sure it's not argument fail; it fails part way through and produces an incomplete .xml output.

Comment: Check to see if your current directory is the same in both cases.

Comment: I suspect you're debugging the wrong process. Your return code is indicative of an access violation in tblastn.  That's unlikely to be directly the fault of your code to spawn the process.  Do you have a C++ debugger?  If so, you could wrap your current command inside the invocation of the debugger.

Comment: @PeterBrittain: tblastn runs completely fine if not run from within my script so the problem seems to stem from some part of the invocation process. I can fire up the debugger and try and track down the error in tblastn but I'm not sure how that will actually help me fix the problem.

Comment: An access violation is basically where the program tries to access an invalid piece of memory.  This is _always_ a bug in the code that hit it and is usually just because it doesn't handle an error condition well - e.g. not checking function return codes for errors/NULL pointers, or running off the end of an array, etc.  Given that the source for tblastn is available, a stack trace for the failure will tell you what it's not handling well - e.g. a file access fails, a memory allocation fails and so a NULL pointer is dereferenced - and so point you at where to look next in your environment.

Comment: @PeterBrittain: I know what an access violation is but knowing what, in particular, caused the access violation doesn't help me unless I also know what is different about the environment it is being run in and, more importantly, how to change it.

Comment: Given that no one can see an obvious difference in the environment, it might be helpful to approach it from the other end of the problem.  If I had to guess right now, it would be that you are using a very large amount of data here, that your Python process is chewing up extra RAM and a memory allocation fails inside tblastn as a result.  Working back from the failure might illumniate the issue.

Comment: @PeterBrittain: The Python process does chew up a lot of data that's true but I've got 16Gb of ram in this thing and it's only at about 31% memory usage according to the Task Manager. What's more if I run the tblastn from the command line while the Python is still running the other tblastn's then it's also fine.

Comment: @PeterBrittain: But you may be right and I may need to attack it from that end. The reason I'm reluctant is the length of time it's likely to take to get the code, install the right version of VS, get it to compile and then debug it. If I can't find another route though it will be my only choice.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no other ideas at this point...  If I were in your place, that's exactly what I'd do next.  Note that you might not need to build the code, depending on whether your existing exes already have debug symbols.

Comment: Does it fail on the same files if you change the order in which they're processed?  What I'm driving at is whether it's a feature of the particular file that causes `tblastn` to fail, or whether it's just the `n`th big file that fails (hinting at memory issues/leakage).

Comment: I still haven't figured this out. I have implemented a workaround - I get it to generate a batch file to run `tblastn` on the offending file and then get the user to run that. Very ugly but at least it is functional.

Comment: It has been over 7 days since you have set this bounty...

Comment: Hope this can help: http://www.0xc0000005.com/

Comment: What's the version of your windows?

Comment: Happens on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012 R2 (windows 8.1, basically)

Answer (score 2):

the error code is likely to be "Access Denied" (although there are 4 code constructs in the windows header files, the Access Denied is the most likely:

```
# for hex 0xc0000005 / decimal -1073741819
  FILE_LOG_INFORMATION_FAILED                                    iasmsg.h
# Information for the %1 log could not be logged to the text
# file %2 in the path %3. Error code: %0
  STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION                                        ntstatus.h
# The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx.
# The memory could not be %s.
  USBD_STATUS_DEV_NOT_RESPONDING                                 usb.h
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_NULL (0x0), Code 0x5
# for hex 0x5 / decimal 5
  ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED                                            winerror.h
# Access is denied.
```

I would start by looking at the user priviledges/credentials which are used to run the original (launching/parent) script, which the childprocess/subprocess inherits its credentials from... then compare this to the credentials which are used when you "run this on cmd prompt" as you have described.

HTH,
Edwin.

Answer (score 2):

1. sub proc that are launched programmatically often get other memory settings (heap size etc.) than interactively launched procs. So try putting some heap/mem checking wrapper around tblastn.exe.
   Your description of "failing on one file but processing in another file list works" shows, that the error is not related to the failing call itself but to some condition caused by the prior activities.
2. output is buffered in memory. If tblastn has a lot of output take communicate() to void (or use) the output of the sub procs.
3. shell=True is not needed for calling executables, it's meant to execute shell build-ins. Using this you wrap tblastn with a senseless cmd.exe.